# Bootstrap 3.0.3 navbar-right and pull-right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I'm working through some Bootstrap tutorials and am using the Bootstrap 3.0.3 version.

I've noticed `navbar-right` floats totally to the right, whereas `pull-right` seems to work as 3.0's `navbar-right` did.

I have placed an example on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7LcLE/).

According to their [blog](http://blog.getbootstrap.com/2013/12/05/bootstrap-3-0-3-released/) on 5 Dec 2013, some modifications have been made, so am wondering if I have either structured the HTML classes incorrectly, or if this is the new approach to menu alignment?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like the 3.0.3 implementation was changed intentionally to cater for this under [#11530](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/11530):

The workaround is to put a padding on the `.navbar-right`:

```
.navbar-right {
   padding-right: 15px;
}
```

If you try and workaround the issue with `pull-right`, you will find the responsive design for `navbar-collapse` will align the menus right.

Comment: I had to do this, `navbar-right` sticks to the right completely unless you do this. I'm using: `<span class="navbar-text navbar-right">`

Comment: Dumb question: does *"will align the menus right"* mean "will align the menus to the right" or "will align the menus correctly"?